# How to set focus on search bar after clicking DropdownSearch in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

How do I focus on the search bar when I click DropdownSearch?

I was trying to find the field that is responsible for this. I found dropdown Builder, but I can't figure it out.

`

```
child: DropdownSearch<String>(
              popupProps: const PopupProps.menu(
                showSearchBox: true,
                showSelectedItems: true,
                searchDelay: Duration(milliseconds: 40)
              ),
              dropdownDecoratorProps: DropDownDecoratorProps(
                dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                  isDense: true,
                )
              ),
              onChanged: (String? value) {
                setState(() {
                  _signs!.signs[index].type = RoadSignType.fromDisplay(value!);
                });
              },
              items: _signTypeItems,
            ),`
```

Answer (score 1):

Dropdown search has a property called "popupProps". Since you are using PopupProps.menu(), inside it you will see another property called searchFieldProps, that receives a TextFieldProps. Inside the TextFieldProps, you have the "autofocus" property. If you set it as true, it will autofocus to the search bar once the popup opens.

Answer (score 0):

Use FocusNade
like

```
FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode();
```

and above or below showSearchBox = true  use
the code so paste

```
focusNode: focusNode;
```

Comment: Search about FocusNode it will help you

Comment: there is no such field